# ctwill - mini indexes for cweb

Tags: literate-programming, knuth

where can i download ctwill?  The ftp.cs.stanford.edu/pub/ctwill/ site doesn't work for me, either is ftp://labrea.stanford.edu/pub/ctwill/.

Thanks,
Raoul

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, but what is `ctwill` and what does it have to do with programming (literate or otherwise)?

Comment: ctwill is a add-on hacked by D. Knuth. It allows mini-indicies for cweb programs on every two page spread. Every variable that is not defined on a two page spread is indexed and the relevant reference is available.

Answer (score 1):

Try http://ftp.cs.stanford.edu/pub/ctwill/ instead. Now if only I could find *TWILL* (CTWILL's plain WEB predecessor), which is what I actually wanted...

**Note:**
The above URL does not appear to play very nicely with NAT, so if you're behind one, I guess you'll have to download it from somewhere else. Also, the Amiga port at http://asciidownload.uni-hd.de/ftp/pub/amiga/dev/misc/CTwill.readme and http://asciidownload.uni-hd.de/ftp/pub/amiga/dev/misc/CTwill.lha might be interesting; it has `.ch` files for warning reduction with ANSI C compilers.