# ctwill - mini indexes for cweb (again)

Tags: literate-programming

I am looking for `ctwill`'s (literate) source code.

I did not find it in CTAN or through Knuth's page.

The links in [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3856425/ctwill-mini-indexes-for-cweb) (ftp://ftp.cs.stanford.edu/pub/ctwill/ and ftp://labrea.stanford.edu/pub/ctwill/) don't seem to work. (And the same links appear in [this cweb repository](https://github.com/ascherer/cwebbin), so no luck there either.)

Any help is deeply appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, [the repository for cweb binaries](https://github.com/ascherer/cwebbin) contains the source for `ctwill`.

The reason why this is not immediately apparent is because of how `ctwill` is generated. Indeed, it is a modified version of `cweave`, which is generated from the very source files of `cweave` using the `changefile` mechanism devised by Knuth.